# Neo4j Cypher: find first matching relationship in a linked list?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Like the question says. The word "first" is important — there may be more relationships that match the same condition.

Real-world use case: every relationship has a timestamp property, and **I want to find the first one that happened before a certain time** (e.g. "before noon"). E.g.:

```
(head) -[time: 9]-> () -[time: 8]-> () -[time: 7]-> ...
```

—

Here's what I had (assume we know what the `head` node is):

```
MATCH (head) -[prevs:next*0..]-> (x) -[rel:next]-> (y)
WHERE NONE(prev IN prevs WHERE prev.time < {time})
AND rel.time < {time}
RETURN x, rel, y
```

That says, "traverse one or more relationships until we find one before `{time}`, AND none of the previous relationships were before `{time}`."

The query works, but surprisingly, **it continues to traverse the list even after it finds one match**. More precisely, it keeps expanding the variable length match — even though the `NONE()` check will clearly fail for the rest.

Maybe this is just a Cypher optimization that has yet to come? In the meantime, **is there a more efficient way I can query this?** (IOW, is there any way I can achieve a "short-circuit" after the first match?)

—

Here's a console link to play around with:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/b4v2tl

**Important:** the setup creates a 1001-node linked list, so it may freeze your browser/tab for a minute or so. I recommend immediately disabling "Toggle Viz" when it unfreezes.

This console example also reverses the time-ordering from the example above, just for simplicity. So paste this query in:

```
MATCH (head:Node {id: 0}) -[prevs:next*0..]-> (x) -[rel:next]-> (y)
WHERE NONE(prev IN prevs WHERE prev.time > 5)
AND rel.time > 5
RETURN x, rel, y
```

That's querying for what should be the fifth relationship in the list.

You'll see Neo4j refuse to execute the query. If you change `0..` to e.g. `0..10`, it'll work. Keep bumping up `10`, and you'll see it get slower and slower. The guard kicks in by `100`.

Comment: I'd report this in github issues so it gets tracked by the dev team--if they don't consider it a bug, at least as a feature request.

Comment: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1961

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MATCH (x)-[r:next]->(y) 
WHERE r.time > {time} 
RETURN x, r, y
ORDER BY r.time
LIMIT 1
```

**EDIT**

If you have your relationships indexed on time property then

```
START r=relationship:rels(time = {time})
MATCH (x)-[r1:next]->(y)-[r]->()
RETURN x,r1,y
```

Comment: That doesn't tell Neo4j to take advantage of the linked list. In the console example I shared, that'll inspect all 1000 relationships, and sort 995 of them in memory.

Comment: check my edited answer. I have used indexing on relationships to pin point your desired time assuming all values you input for time are integers.

Comment: Thanks, but that assumes I know the exact time I'm looking for. In this case, I don't. I just want one e.g. "before noon", and there may be no relationship that happened exactly at noon.

Answer (score 0):

This is a shortcoming of cypher before 2.1 (which will hopefully address it).

If it is urgent, check out a unmanaged extension that does this in a few lines of java:

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-activity-stream

https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-activity-stream/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/example/activity/ActivityStream.java#L59

Comment: Did this ever get addressed in later versions of Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was addressed last year in Neo4j 3.0.3 as seen in this commit - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/2c5c3dd